# converting cutoff frequency of lowpass filter for 2D images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, lowpass-filter

If we want to lowpass filter an image by `0.3xpi rad/sample` by using `h = fspecial('average', size)`, how shall we determine `size` parameter corresponding to `0.3xpi rad/sample` in the following code?

```
lp_filter = fspecial('average', size);
img = imfilter(original,lp_filter,'replicate');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter size is the inverse of the cut-off.  So, for a simple filter like average, if you had a size of 1 pixel (i.e. no averaging), the cut-off would be at pi rad/sample.  So, the nearest integer to 0.3 pi rad/sample would be a size of 3 pixels.

The maths is a bit more complicated than that, but this is a useful rule of thumb in this case.

Comment: Is there any reference that you suggest for the math?

Comment: Any good textbook on signal or image processing will include information on the Fourier transform.  There are two key aspects to the problem (if you want the detail), and that is (i) it is a sampled data system, so the averaging filter is periodic in the frequency domain, and (ii) you are looking at a very non-ideal filter.  A quick search brings up [link](http://zimmer.fresnostate.edu/~pkinman/pdfs/Sampling.pdf) which shows the time-frequency dual relationship.

Comment: You can test out what the frequency response of any function in Matlab is pretty quickly.  For example, the averaging by 3: `x=ones(1,3); X=fft(x,1024); plot(20*log10(abs(X)));` will plot, on a dB scale, the magnitude of the frequency response.  (You'll need to normalise the x-axis to be able to work out the frequency, but in this case, 1024 corresponds to 2pi).  By increasing the length of x, you'll readily see the relationship I was talking about.